# Modificar texto de archivo txt en vb.net

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, powershell

Como podría tomar los valores del siguiente archivo .txt para reemplzarlo en el comando New-PSDrive:

```
Name ProviderName             
---- ------------             
F:   \\xxxx1\ejemplo   
G:   \\xxxx2\ejemplo
M:   \\xxxx3\ejemplo
```

.

```
New-PSDrive -Name "F" -Root "\\xxxx1\ejemplo  "  -Persist "FileSystem"
New-PSDrive -Name "G" -Root "\\xxxx2\ejemplo  "  -Persist "FileSystem"
New-PSDrive -Name "M" -Root "\\xxxx3\ejemplo  "  -Persist "FileSystem"
```

donde la letra seguida de -name la obtengo del .txt al igual que la ruta. Luego el resultado guardarlo en un .txt

Esto lo estoy queriendo hacer en vb.net.
Desde ya, muchas gracias!

```
Private Sub btnexpredes_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnexpredes.Click

        Dim lista As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

        Dim redes As String
        Dim linea As String

        redes = Environ$("userprofile") & "\Desktop\Configuracion\Exportacion\redes.txt"

        Dim red As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(redes)

        For Each i As String In red
            linea = "New-PSDrive3 -Name" & "red" & "-Persist FileSystem"

            ' lista.Add(linea)
            ListBox3.Items.Add(i)

        Next



        MsgBox("Redes exportadas correctamente", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
    End Sub
```

Eso es lo q voy haciendo pero no sabemos hacerlo

Comment: Hola, las preguntas sin código ni investigación no son bien recibidas, si tienes algo ya escrito por favor compartelo.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu caso lo único que te falta es primero hacer un Split a tu linea para obtener los dos resultados que necesitas, y siguiente concatenarlos a tu cadena, en cada ciclo de tu for.

Con esto separas una cadena en dos, buscando por los : que es un carácter fácil de identificar en todas las columnas `Dim lineas = i.Split(":").

Y con `"New-PSDrive3 -Name " & lineas(0).Trim() & "-Root """ & lineas(1).Trim() & """ -Persist FileSystem"`

Aqui obtienes de tu array las posiciones que necesitas reemplazar la primera corresponde a la letra y la segunda a la ruta.

Solo de preferencia aplica un trim para evitar que lleve espacios vacíos al inicio y al final

El resultado de tu función quedaría así.

```
    Private Sub btnexpredes_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnexpredes.Click

        Dim linea As String

        redes = Environ$("userprofile") & "\Desktop\Configuracion\Exportacion\redes.txt"

        Dim red As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(redes)

        For Each i As String In red
            Dim lineas = i.Split(":")

            linea = "New-PSDrive3 -Name " & lineas(0).Trim() & "-Root """ & lineas(1).Trim() & """ -Persist FileSystem"

            ListBox3.Items.Add(linea)

        Next


        Dim SaveFile As System.IO.StreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter("rutaArchivo")
        For Each item As String In ListBox3.Items
            SaveFile.WriteLine(ListBox3.Items)
        Next

        SaveFile.Close()

        MsgBox("Redes exportadas correctamente", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
    End Sub
```

Y para lo que necesitas de guardar ese resultado en un archivo tal vez esto te funcione https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595279/c-sharp-save-all-items-in-a-listbox-to-text-file/20595349.

Comment: Hola, no me esta dejando con esta linea
  linea = "New-PSDrive3 -Name" & lineas(0).Trim() & "-Root" & lineas(1).Trim() & "-Persist FileSystem" me dice System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' Sabes que podria ser?

Comment: valida que tu linea no sean los encabezados, en este caso que no contenga `"Name ProviderName` o `"---- ------------ "`, si las contiene, recorre a la siguiente linea

Comment: o la otra opción es valida despues de el split si la longitud es =2, algo asi como  `If lineas.Length = 2 Then`